# What class would this be covered in?

Tags: differential-geometry, education

Would the material in [this section of a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) be covered in a standard course on Differential Geometry, or should I look elsewhere to learn those sorts of things? Specifically, topics like solid angles, line/surface/volume elements, and so forth. I have taken vector calculus, which did not get into these topics in any detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard differential geometry class would certainly contain this material, but it would probably not spend significant time on them. This is more the flavor of a multivariable calculus/analysis class; if this wasn't covered to your satisfaction in yours, you might want to study these on your own.

Comment: Do you have any books/references that such classes would use which spend more time on these topics? My class was much more "formal" - we did not discuss things like volume elements except in passing.

Comment: A standard multivariable calculus book should have what you're looking for--perhaps *Calculus of Several Variables* by Serge Lang. There are more theoretical books too if you have a strong background in analysis. If you actually want to actually *compute* line, surface, and volume integrals, a book aimed at scientists or engineers would probably be more appropriate. I recommend *Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences* by Boas or *Basic Training in Mathematics* by Shankar.